# Using LongAdder to calculate a max value for a statistical counter?

Tags: java, concurrency, statistics, java-8, java.util.concurrent

We collect some statistics using AtomicLongs.  Some users are seeing contention on these and have suggested using LongAdder instead.  However I see no way to calculate the maximum value as we are currently doing with the Atomic:

```
AtomicLong _current, _total, _max;
...

void add(long delta)
{
  long current = _current.addAndGet(delta);
  if (delta>0)
  {
    _total.addAndGet(delta);
    long max = _max.get();
    while (current > max)
    {
      if (_max.compareAndSet(max, current))
        break;
      max = _max.get();
    }
 }
```

So I think we can replace `_total` easily enough with a `LongAdder`, but because we do `_current.addAndGet(delta)` that will not work well for a `LongAdder`, nor can we do cas operation for the `_max' value.

Are there any good algorithms for collecting such statistics based on `LongAdder` or similar scalable lock free constructs?

Actually, whiles I'm asking, our stats typically update 6 to 10 AtomicLongs.  If we are seeing contention anyway, could it be possibly be better to just grab a lock and update 6 to 10 normal longs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want `LongAdder`, but `LongAccumulator` here: you want `new LongAccumulator(Math::max, Long.MIN_VALUE)`, which does the right thing here.  `LongAdder` is a special case of `LongAccumulator`.

Comment: Ah that will allow `_max` to be turned into a `LongAccumulator`, but it doesn't help with the addAndGet semantics needed for `_current`.      However it still allows 3 AtomicLongs to be replaced with 1 AtomicLong, 1 LongAdder and 1 LongAccumulator

Comment: @gregw: whether you can simplify it further, depends on what you are actually doing with these values outside the method you have posted. From that single method you have shown, all three will always contain the same value and hence, could be replaced by a single `LongAdder`…

Comment: @Holger The three values are not always the same because negative deltas can be passed in.

Comment: @gregw: I see. This makes me wonder about the actual use case. If you assume high contention at this point, the actual result depends on the unpredictable thread scheduling, as accumulating `-1, +1, -1, +1` will yield a different maximum value than accumulating `+1, +1, -1, -1`,  even if there are only nanoseconds making the difference (we might actually encounter all four values at the same time, but the `AtomicLong` enforces an arbitrary serial update order)…